# Ms graph API v1.0: HideForUser and a few other methods do not show up in .Net 5

Tags: graph, .net-5

though the docs here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chat-hideforuser?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) said we could use them, with c# sample code too, but we don't see them at all after having added the sdk to the project. Note we are already able to add new chat with members and fetch messages.

a few others too that have same issue:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chat-unhideforuser?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chat-markchatreadforuser?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chat-markchatunreadforuser?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

is there any dependency or steps we missed?

Answer (score 0):

resolved the problem -- somehow the version (4.34.0) I used was out of date, and the latest version 4.49.0 does have these APIs